# Behavior of Green's function $G(x)$ for $x\to 0$ for general second order PDE

Tags: elliptic-pde, asymptotics, linear-pde, green-function

Let's have a generic elliptic second order PDE in $n$-dimensions with a Dirac delta on the right hand side

$$\left( a_{ij}(x) \partial_i \partial_j + b_j(x) \partial_j + c(x) \right) G(x) = \delta(x)$$

Here $a_{ij}(x), b_j(x), c(x)$ are given and behave in a simple way around $x \to 0$, they have expansions

$$a_{ij}(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^\alpha} \left( \frac{A_{ij}}{x^k} + \frac{B_{ij}}{x^{k-1}} + \ldots \right)$$

$$b_{j}(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^\beta} \left( \frac{C_{j}}{x^l} + \frac{D_{j}}{x^{l-1}} + \ldots \right)$$

$$c(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^\gamma} \left( \frac{E}{x^m} + \frac{F}{x^{m-1}} + \ldots \right)$$

The leading non-integer exponents $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ may be positive or negative or zero, and also the integers $k,l,m$ may be positive or negative or zero.

What I'm interested in is the behavior of $G(x)$ around $x\to 0$. If I assume there are no logarithms in $G(x)$, schematically it will look similar,

$$G(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^\delta} \left( \frac{G_0}{x^p} + \frac{G_1}{x^{p-1}} + \ldots \right)$$

Intuitively, I'd think that in order to determine the above series I'd need to consider only a few terms from the expansions of $a_{ij}, b_j, c$ because these few terms should determine the first few terms of the expansion of $G(x)$ for $x\to 0$. In other words if I'm satisfied with a finite number of terms in $G(x)$ I only need to keep a finite number of terms from $a_{ij}, b_j, c$.

Is this correct?